# Error when I put decimal numbers android studio

Tags: android, database, paypal

I'm implementing a donate button with paypal in my android application. Everything is fine until when I put numbers with decimals I get an error, but when I put whole numbers, I do not. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I searched for it on the internet but I can not find anything

Error:

```
02-09 22:35:29.256 30695-30695/dev.mros.espanyaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "0,12"
                                                                     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
                                                                     at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
                                                                     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
                                                                     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
                                                                     at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:344)
                                                                     at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:425)
                                                                     at dev.mros.espanyaapp.Paypal.getPayment(Paypal.java:72)
                                                                     at dev.mros.espanyaapp.Paypal.onClick(Paypal.java:49)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public class Paypal extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//The views
private Button buttonPay;
private EditText editTextAmount;

//Payment Amount
private String paymentAmount;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paypal);
    buttonPay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPay);

    editTextAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
    buttonPay.setOnClickListener(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
    startService(intent);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    getPayment();
}
//Paypal intent request code to track onActivityResult method
public static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 123;


//Paypal Configuration Object
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        // Start with mock environment.  When ready, switch to sandbox (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
        .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .clientId(PayPalConfig.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
private void getPayment() {
    //Getting the amount from editText
    paymentAmount = editTextAmount.getText().toString();

    //Creating a paypalpayment
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), "USD", "Simplified Coding Fee",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    //Creating Paypal Payment activity intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    //putting the paypal configuration to the intent
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    //Puting paypal payment to the intent
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

    //Starting the intent activity for result
    //the request code will be used on the method onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //If the result is from paypal
    if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE) {

        //If the result is OK i.e. user has not canceled the payment
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Getting the payment confirmation
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

            //if confirmation is not null
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    //Getting the payment details
                    String paymentDetails = confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    Log.i("paymentExample", paymentDetails);

                    //Starting a new activity for the payment details and also putting the payment details with intent
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class)
                            .putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
                            .putExtra("PaymentAmount", paymentAmount));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 0,12? why is there a , and not a .?

Comment: a comma is not a decimal. you can clearly see the error is you read the message

Comment: however, 0.12 is a double, NOT a long.

Comment: And how could I implement it?

Comment: implement what? if you are working with MONEY, then they are DOUBLES, not longs, not integers. change the data type to double and stay away from long.

Comment: And how could I do that?

Comment: @DroiDev The OP is not explicitly using `long`. The real problem is related to locale.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice just really looked at the code when he asked how to fix it. String.valueOf(paymentAmount).. your answer is probably right on. hes passing in a , and not a . through the ET

Answer (score 1):

In the US, we use `.` as the decimal point rather than `,` as is used in some countries. The easiest fix is to require users to type numbers as `0.12`, for example, instead of `0,12`. If you want to allow `,` to be typed in decimal numbers, you will need to use `Locale` and `NumberFormat` to parse the input from the `EditText`.

Comment: How could it change?

Comment: @zzxbx You should read about [locales](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html) and `NumberFormat`.